# React: Render a child element from an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to pull a children element from a collection but I'm not able to, it doesn't seem to find the properties,  I know I'm close to get what I want but I'm stuck on this. I'm using meteor 1.6 with React 16

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Col, Thumbnail, Button, Modal, Row, Form, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Medicamento } from '../api/medicamento.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class ListMeds extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){

        function RenderLotes(){
            const lotesArray = this.props.meds.Lotes.map((lista) => 
              // The console indicates Cannot read property 'meds' of undefined
                <div key={lista.codigoLote}>
                    <h3>{lista.codigoLote}</h3>
                </div>
            );
            return(
                <div>{lotesArray}</div>
            );
        }//function RenderLotes ends here
        return(
        <div>
            <Col md={4}>
                    <div align="center"><strong>{this.props.meds.name}</strong></div>
                    <div align="center"><em>{this.props.meds.principio}</em></div>  
            </Col>
    //the two lines above work fine, but crashes when I try to render the function
            <Col md={4}>
                    <div><RenderLotes/></div>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}
ListMeds.propTypes = {
    meds: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: where do you close the `<div>` tag in your main return?

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in RenderLotes is not the same `this` as in the outer render() function.. But you probably don't even need RenderLotes like that, just make the array like Andrew Kim suggested.. Or, if you really wanted to have it, something like this should work:

```
function RenderLotes(props) {
    const lotesArray = props.meds.Lotes.map((lista) => 
        <div key={lista.codigoLote}>
            <h3>{lista.codigoLote}</h3>
        </div>
    );
    return(
        <div>{lotesArray}</div>
    );
}

// later:
<div><RenderLotes meds={this.props.meds} /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the console error says, `this.props` is undefined within your `RenderLotes()` function, suggesting that this is a scoping issue; the `this` in your `RenderLotes()` does not refer to the React Component, but to something else.

One option would be to define the `RenderLotes()` function outside of the `render()` function, declaring both functions at the same level :

```
RenderLotes() {...}
render() {...}
```

Then, in your JSX, call it this way:

`<div>{this.RenderLotes()}</div>`

Answer (score -1):

Put your props in state when in your constructor

```
export default class ListMeds extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            meds = props.meds
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
           {this.state.meds.map(lista => {
               return (
                   <div key={lista.codigoLote}>
                       <h3>{lista.codigoLote}</h3>
                   </div>
               )
           })}
        )
    }
```

And make sure when you render that you are actually passing a prop called meds

```
ReactDOM.render(<ListMeds meds={meds} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but your code should look probably more like this:

```
render(){
  let lotesArray = this.props.meds.Lotes.map((lista) => {
    return(
      <div key={lista.codigoLote}>
        <h3>{lista.codigoLote}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Col md={4}>
        <div align="center"><strong>{this.props.meds.name}</strong></div>
        <div align="center"><em>{this.props.meds.principio}</em></div>  
      </Col>

      <Col md={4}>
        <div>{lotesArray}</div>
      </Col>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all if console says that `meds` property is undefined it means that it doesn't exist hence you cannot iterate over it. Second thing is how you invoke `RenderLotes` function. `<div><RenderLotes/></div>` this won't work. Instead you need to change it to `<div>{this.RenderLotes()}</div>`. And move `RenderLotes` function declaration out of `render` method. Also you don't close `div` tag in `render` function. Change the code to something like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Col, Thumbnail, Button, Modal, Row, Form, FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Medicamento } from '../api/medicamento.js'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class ListMeds extends Component {
    renderLotes = () => this.props.meds.Lotes.map(lista =>
      (<div key={lista.codigoLote}>
        <h3>{lista.codigoLote}</h3>
      </div>))

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Col md={4}>
            <div align="center"><strong>{this.props.meds.name}</strong></div>
            <div align="center"><em>{this.props.meds.principio}</em></div>
          </Col>
          <Col md={4}>
            <div>{!!this.props.meds && this.renderLotes()}</div>
          </Col>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
ListMeds.propTypes = {
  meds: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}
```